# Bug report: disappearing table/code block

Tags: bug, abcjs

Appears in this answer here:

https://music.stackexchange.com/a/90663/62794

After page load, the contents of the code block disappears. It renders properly in the editor, but not on the normal page.

I suspect it may be related to the abcjs integration.

Comment: This is more likely due to jtab. jtab is quite greedy when trying to render and the duplicate has a work around if you need to use the code blocks for non abcjs or jtab.